# IBM Domino - ($Rooms) view in names.nsf not up-to-date with R&R database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm relying on the `$(Rooms)` view in the names.nsf database to obtain a list of rooms available on the domino server. I'm also using it to check the room autoprocess restrictions (`AutoProcessType` and `AutoProcessUserList`).
However, I have noticed that this information sometimes takes ages to update.
I change the autoprocess type to diabled (`AutoProcessType=D`) in the database (using Domino Admin, not directly), yet the `($Rooms)` view still shows me old `AutoProcessType` for a very long amount of time, I spent more than 10 minutes waiting without any success. I tried running various commands, such as `tell rnrmgr validate` etc. but finally ended up restarting the domino server, finally resulting in the field changing.

This leads me to problems, because my app still shows the rooms as available, while they have disabled reservations. The notes client somehow gets this data updated instantly, after I disable the reservations I cannot see the room anymore.

I ended up with a temporary solution of looping through all entries in the `$(Rooms)` view of the R&R database in which the room is located (`MailFile` field) to find the according room from names.nsf, and get the AutoProcessType from there. This way, I see the changes instantly, however I don't like this approach.

Is there any other way to do it? How does the notes client get the autoprocess restrictions so fast?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever change you make to a resource in the resource reservation database is propagated to the names.nsf through the Administration Process adminp.

the request is beeing put in the "admin4.nsf" on the server where the resource database is. This database then needs to be replicated to the administration server of the domain (might be the same) and there the adminp will pick it up and execute it and change the document in the view. As soon as names.nsf is replicated back to the originating server you have the information available.

Depending on replication interval this can last hours or even longer. If no replication takes place (all on the same server), then at least you need to wait until adminp runs.

This can be anywhere from immediate to multiple minutes. 
Adminp can be forced to run by sending console command "tell adminp process new", but you need special rights to do so.

I would get the document from ($Rooms)- view, then open the resource database (MailServer and MailFile- fields in document) and get the resource document from there from the ($Resources)- view... there you get the information in real time...